# Eclipse not allowing to use a setter defined in parent class

Tags: java, constructor, setter, getter

I'm glad I found this forum.
I'm new to Java( beginner) and learning how to use setters, getters and constructor. I ran into an error and don't know how to resolve it. Please help me in isolating this error.
I wrote two classes, first one is a simple java app called MyCalc that has 2 methods Add(), Multiply() and a setter setXY.  MyCalc Class is instantiated using static void main().

2nd class "MyCalcTest" calls the first class. The standalone java app MyCalc runs fine without errors. But when I try to use setter 'setXY' from MycalcTest to set values for parameters, elipse doesn't allow me to use setXY. Any reason why ?

Here is the code for both classes:

1)

```
public class MyCalc {

    private double x, y;

    //findout why it's throwing an error using setXY method from MyClacTest class
    public void setXY(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    //this constructor with params works fine when called from MyCalcTest class
    /*public MyCalc(double a, double b){
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
    }*/

    //getters
    public double Add(){
        return x+y;
    }

    public double Multiple(){
        return (x * y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //this works when called MyCalc with parameters
        //MyCalc calc = new MyCalc(5, 5);

        MyCalc calc = new MyCalc();
        calc.setXY(5, 5);
        System.out.println("Addition: " + calc.Add());
        System.out.println("multiplication :" + calc.Multiple());

    }

}
```

2)

```
public class MyCalcTest {



        //this works when called MyCalc with parameters
        //MyCalc calc = new MyCalc(5, 5);

        MyCalc calc = new MyCalc();

        //this doesn't workto set x,y why??
        calc.setXY(5, 5);


}
```

Comment: If you have a question about something that's not working, ALWAYS include the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
calc.setXY(5, 5);
```

Has to be inside a method/constructor/ initialization block.

```
public class MyCalcTest {

    MyCalc calc;
    public MyCalcTest (){
    calc = new MyCalc();
    calc.setXY(5, 5);

      }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it's working now, Thanks a lot for your immediate reply. I'm still in front of my pc and it greatly helped me.